# Handling unencodable characters in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

Given an input string and an encoding, I want to process each character in the input string as follows:

- If the codepoint can be encoded, then encode it;
- If not, output (the encoding of) the string `&#xUUUU;` where UUUU is the hex value of the Unicode codepoint.

I've read through the .NET documentation for `Encoder` and `EncoderFallback`, and I can see how to get notified when an unencodable character is found, but I can't see any way to output something that actually depends on the particular character in question.

Any ideas?

Looking a bit deeper (thanks @JosefZ), I see that the description of the `EncoderFallback` class says it supports three mechanisms, including:

> Best-fit fallback, which maps valid Unicode characters that cannot be
> encoded to an approximate equivalent. For example, a best-fit fallback
> handler for the ASCIIEncoding class might map Æ (U+00C6) to AE (U+0041 +
> U+0045). A best-fit fallback handler might also be implemented to transliterate one alphabet (such as Cyrillic) to another (such as
> Latin or Roman). The .NET Framework does not provide any public
> best-fit fallback implementations.

which would appear to be the one I am after: so I have to work out how to write my own implementation of `EncoderFallback`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. Could [this code example help?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoderexceptionfallback?view=net-6.0#examples)

Comment: Thanks. It led me to the fact that `EncoderFallbackException` has properties identifying the first unencodable character. That could be useful, though it's still going to be very laborious having to re-encode the string fragments before and after that character.

Comment: I feel the `EncoderFallbackBuffer` approach is probably better than using exceptions, but the documentation is pretty unhelpful, with no examples.

Comment: How do you want to show a high/low surrogate pair? You could do `&#xUUUU;&#xUUUU;` or you could do `&#xUUUUUUUU;`

Comment: I'm generating XML, so I need to follow XML rules, which output the single Unicode codepoint, not the two surrogates.

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a proper XML encoder, such as `XDocument`

Comment: My product (Saxon) includes a "proper XML encoder", which unlike XDocument has to follow the W3C serialisation rules; I want to extend it to support more encodings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `EncoderFallback` and `EncoderFallbackBuffer` to do what you want

```cs
public class HexFallback : EncoderFallback
{
    public override int MaxCharCount { get { return int.MaxValue; } }   // we can handle any amount of chars
    public override EncoderFallbackBuffer CreateFallbackBuffer(){ return new HexFallbackBuffer(); }
}

public class HexFallbackBuffer : EncoderFallbackBuffer
{
    int _currentPos;   // current position of invalid char encoding
    char _charToEncode;   // first or main char
    char _charToEncode2;  // lower pair of surrogate if any
    
    public override bool Fallback(char charUnknown, int index)
    {
        Reset();
        _charToEncode = charUnknown;   // store char
        return true;
    }
    
    public override bool Fallback(char charUnknownHigh, char charUnknownLow, int index)
    {
        Reset();
        _charToEncode = charUnknownHigh;   // store high and low surrogates
        _charToEncode2 = charUnknownLow;
        return true;        
    }
    
    public override int Remaining { get { return 8 - _currentPos + (_charToEncode2 != (char)0 ? 8 : 0); } }   // 8 chars per invalid char
    
    public override void Reset()
    {
        _charToEncode = (char)0;
        _charToEncode2 = (char)0;
        _currentPos = 0;
    }
    
    public override bool MovePrevious()   // can we move backwards in our encoding
    {
        if(_currentPos == 0)
            return false;
        _currentPos -= 1;
        return true;
    }
    
    public override char GetNextChar()
    {
        if(_charToEncode2 != (char)0 && _currentPos == 8)   // if we have a surrogate
        {
            _charToEncode = _charToEncode2;   // move low surrogate to main
            _charToEncode2 = (char)0;
            _currentPos = 0;   // and start again
        }
        
        char result;
        switch(_currentPos)
        {
        case 0:
            result = '&';
            break;
        case 1:
            result = '#';
            break;
        case 2:
            result = 'x';
            break;
        case 3:
            result = NibbleToHex(((int)_charToEncode) >> 12);   // shift 12 bits
            break;
        case 4:
            result = NibbleToHex(((int)_charToEncode) >> 8 & 0x0F);  // shift 8 and mask the rest
            break;
        case 5:
            result = NibbleToHex(((int)_charToEncode) >> 4 & 0x0F);  // shift 4 and mask the rest
            break;
        case 6:
            result = NibbleToHex(((int)_charToEncode) & 0x0F); //  mask all high bits
            break;
        case 7:
            result = ';';
            break;
        default:
            return (char)0;
        }
        
        _currentPos++;
        return result;
    }
    
    char NibbleToHex(int nibble)    // convert 4 bits to hex char
    {
        return (char)(
            nibble < 10
            ? nibble + (int)'0'  // Return a character from '0' to '9'
            : nibble + (int)'7'  // Return A to F
            );
    }
}
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lARFjg)

You use it like this

```cs
var encoder = Encoding.ASCII.GetEncoder();
encoder.Fallback = new HexFallback();

var str = "Æ";
var buffer = new byte[1000];

var length = encoder.GetBytes(str.ToCharArray(), 0, str.Length, buffer, 0, true);

// write out encoded string
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, length));
```

Comment: Nice however the code at _dotnetfiddle_ generates an additional `&#x0000;` for each ASCII character, e.g.  `var str = "ÆrŘaрbρ";` -> `&#x00C6;r&#x0000;&#x0158;a&#x0000;&#x0440;b&#x0000;&#x03C1;&#xD83D;&#xDC4D;`. Tested chars are - `Æ` (U+00C6,  *Latin Capital Letter Ae*)
- `r` (U+0072,  *Latin Small Letter R*)
- `Ř` (U+0158,  *Latin Capital Letter R With Caron*)
- `a` (U+0061,  *Latin Small Letter A*)
- `р` (U+0440,  *Cyrillic Small Letter Er*)
- `b` (U+0062,  *Latin Small Letter B*)
- `ρ` (U+03C1,  *Greek Small Letter Rho*)
- `` (U+1F44D, *THUMBS UP SIGN (0xd83d,0xdc4d)*).

Comment: @JosefZ There's weird state machine effects going on, should be working now